# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not get next result for class Entity

Tags: android, ormlite

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
 private  Collection<Entity> entityCollection  ;
```

I see that I have one element in my entityCollection from the type ForeignCollectionField

```
  public  ArrayList<Entity> getCachedEntityCollection() {
            if (entityCollectionArray==null)
            {

                return  new ArrayList<Entity>(entityCollection);
            }
            return  entityCollectionArray;
        }
```

but when I execute this line

```
return  new ArrayList<Entity>(entityCollection);
```

I got this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not get next result for class Entity
 at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.next(SelectIterator.java:183)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection.toArray(LazyForeignCollection.java:217)
            at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:97)
```

Comment: What is the "Caused" by part of that exception?  Maybe the database was closed or something?